# What is "..." in Angular2? What its purpose?

Tags: angular, typescript

What is **...** in Angular? And what it is called?
I'm thinking what is the use of "...flash" in addFlash method where it is a parameter in the array.push()?

And also in the toggleFlash method why there is "..." if we can just use *this* keyword?

```
flashs: IFlash[] = [];

flashs$ = new BehaviorSubject<IFlash[]>(this.flashs);

addFlash(flash: IFlash) {
    this.flashs.push({
        ...flash,
        show: false,
        id: getRandomNumber()
    });
}

toggleFlash(id: number) {
    const index = this.flashs.findIndex(flash => flash.id === id);
    this.flashs = [
        ...this.flashs.slice(0, index),
        {
            ...this.flashs[index],
            show: !this.flashs[index].show
        },
        ...this.flashs.slice(index + 1)
    ];
    this.flashs$.next(this.flashs);
}
```

Comment: It's a feature of ES6, *Spread Syntax*, not part of Angular. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: @TonyNgo I think not. Because my question sounds I don't really know what it is and what it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...` is [es6 Spread_syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in your code `...this.flashs`  will add `this.flashs` items to the array where you'r use it while `{...this.flashs[index]` will add the properties of the object at given index to the object where you'r using it read the comments in code below for further explanation

```
 this.flashs = [
        ...this.flashs.slice(0, index),//slice flashs array and add result items here like obj1,obj2....
        {
            ...this.flashs[index],//get object at given index and add that object properties here like prop1:val,prop2:val,...
            show: !this.flashs[index].show
        },
        ...this.flashs.slice(index + 1)
    ];
```